# Mysterious Sound

Tags: windows-8, audio, system-sounds, hp-laptop

I was working with an old computer (New enough to have Windows 8 as the base operating system, old enough to be shut down for a minimum of 4 years without being touched or turned on) and I was getting rid of a load of virus's, malware, and other such issues. Mysteriously, the entire time I was working, the computer was making a phone call sound at random intervals. Opening the Volume Mixer and waiting for the sound to happen revealed that it was in the "System" volume section. As that was no help, I continued removing things with the sound off, hoping something would be deleted to end the sound. To my dismay, after eliminating all of the Virus's, malwares, and other such problems, the only other notable issue being the Snap.Do taskbar, the sound kept playing. It was somewhere in the system, but I had no idea where. I searched high and low, deleted a mass ton of non-factory folders and personal folders (with owners permission) and nothing got rid of the sound. Soon enough, I restarted the computer and let it go through 12 massive updates (likely due to not being used for 4 years) and the sound still plays.

I promised the owner I would fix this issue, but I have no idea what could be making the sound, no idea how to look for it, and the only piece of malware at this point is like I said earlier, the Snap.Do it taskbar.

Someone please help.

EDIT:

I understand that I have not given much information, however I am giving you all the information that I have myself. I was hoping that someone here has had the same problem as me before, and found a solution.
I will talk with them about completely factory resetting the system, however, I am surprised at the negative reactions to someone just trying to ask for help on a confusing problem.

Comment: I suggest to re-install windows entirely. If there has been that many viruses and malwares and such, I'm sure you didn't get rid of all of them. You will be much better and faster off by just re-installing the entire system.

Comment: You have simply not given us enough information for us to identify the source of the sound.  It sounds like malware.  It sounds like it would be far easier for you to simply reinstall Windows then hunt for something you cannot identify.

Comment: Did you go through the various system sounds in the Control Panel to find if an error or warning sound was to blame? But, as others note, based on the other information you have provided, I too would highly recommend a fresh, clean reinstall.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Re-imaging definitely sounds like the best option (can of course copy any remaining user folders (media, etc.) and duplicate them onto an identical profile on the reimaged OS.

However, if this is not an option you or your client are willing to pursue then if you can determine what is the source of the sound (which notification or action elicits the noise), you can adjust the sounds/profile manually via “TaskBar > Sounds” to replace or remove any noise from said source.

[image: TaskBar>Sounds]